# Using It's Own Call as One The Parameters in a Function call statement

Tags: c

Here Is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int mul(int,int);

int main()
{    
    int sum,m,n;    
    scanf("%d%d",&m,&n);    
    sum=mul(10,mul(m,n));    
    printf("%d",sum);
}

int mul(int x,int y)    
{    
    int sum;    
    sum=x+y;    
    return(sum);    
}
```

Input

10

5

Output

25

Can someone tell me why I get 25 as output? Was the function called 2 times?
 One during parameters and other time during sum?

Comment: Calling the summing function`mul` is intended to confuse the enemy?

Comment: What do you expect? What is your problem?

Comment: `mul(10,mul(m,n))` <- there are two function calls to `mul`

Comment: @Olaf: OP probably didn't spot the nested calls to `mul` in `sum=mul(10,mul(m,n));`

Comment: Note: `return` is not a function, but a statement. Using parens around the expression is not only pointless, but can result in subtle errors with typos. Just don't.

Comment: The real answer here is "learn how to use a debugger". Then you can single step through your code and see exactly what is happening every step of the way.

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem: So? A programmer - even a beginner - can be expected to read his code carefully (isn't that taught at school anymore?) and at least read [ask].

Comment: @Olaf: Fair enough, that's why I added that bit about using a debugger or just look through the assembler output to my answer

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem: I agree using a debugger should be something a beginner should learn soon. But then, this question does not even need looking at the compiled program. IOW: OP did not a bit of research. Sounds like some did the homework for her ...

Comment: @Olaf: you're right. It's a poor question. Easy to answer, just as easy to answer as it would've been to spend the time writing the question by looking at the code a bit more carefully...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's perfectly simple:

```
sum=mul(10,mul(m,n));
```

You're calling `mul()` with 10 as the first argument, and the return value of `mul(m, n)` as the second argument.

`m` and `n` are 10 and 5, so `mul(10, 5)` returns 15. The statement in your `main` function then evaluates to this:

```
sum = mul(10, 15);
```

Which is 25.

TL;DR: ***yes, `mul()` is called twice. Once with `m` and `n` as arguments. The second time with the sum of `m` and `n`, adding 10***

Using a debugger, or even looking at the assembler output generated by the compiler would've told you there were 2 successive calls to `mul`.
And yes, as others have rightfully pointed out: reading the help section (in particular [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)) would be a good idea. It explains that you're expected to do the sensible debugging/diagnostic steps yourself. Only if that didn't solve the problem should you post a question here:

> Explain how you encountered the problem you're trying to solve, and any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself.

You merely state that, given input X, you get output Y, and you don't know why.

Comment: Thanks For THe Help!
Would Keep It In Mind from now on.